# Как сделать возврат к форме, после всплывающего сообщения?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Решил проблему с выводом сообщения после отправки формы ajax, но как теперь сделать, чтобы после сообщения происходил возврат к форме с очищенными инпутами

```js
function sendOrder2(form) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "send.php",
    method: "post",
    data: jQuery(form).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery('#send-form2').html("<div id='message'></div>");
      jQuery('#message').html("<h2 style='color: green'>Вопрос отправлен!</h2>")
        .append("<p style='font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;'>В ближайшее время менеджер свяжется с вами!</p>")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(1500, function() {
          $('#message').append("<i class=\"icon-ok\"></i>");
        })
    }
  });
  return false;

}
```

```css
.form-control {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 6px 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form action="send2.php" onsubmit="sendOrder2(this); return false;" method="post" id="send-form2" class="news-letter">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Имя" required>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Текст сообщения..." required></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-9 col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
        <button type="submit" id="showModal" class="btn btn-default btn-default-primary">Отправить</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Т.е., должно чиститься поле input от данных? Если да, то можно:
$('input').attr('value', '').

Comment: да, что бы поля были пустыми